# Rails sprockets using wrong CDN when rendering image-url in scss files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn, sprockets

I am having a problem where the CDN url generated via sprockets after an asset precompile does not match the CDN url defined in config.action_controller.asset_host

I am using asset_sync to upload all my my assets to a bucket. Here is my asset_sync.yml file:

```
   defaults: &defaults
  fog_provider: 'AWS'
  aws_access_key_id: "sdfgdsfdfgdsfgd"
  aws_secret_access_key: "sdfgsdfgdfgdfgsdfgsdg"
  fog_directory: "bucketnamehere"

  existing_remote_files: delete
  gzip_compression: true
  manifest: true

local:
  <<: *defaults
```

And in my environments/local.rb file i have:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "fffefeefefef.cloudfront.net"
  config.requirejs.run_config['baseUrl'] = config.action_controller.asset_host

  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

  config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
    if path =~ /\.(css)\z/
      full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
      app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
      if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
        puts "including asset: " + full_path
        true
      else
        puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
        false
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Everything seems to precompile fine and i can see all the assets on my bucket and i can access them via `fffefeefefef.cloudfront.net`.

**However, there is a major issue.**

in all of my .scss files, when i used image-url, sprockets is using the wrong CDN name. For instance, if i had the following css:

```
.discount-title{
    background: image-url('deleted/txt-discount.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

its rendering it as:

```
.discount-title {
    background: url(//rtrtrtrtrtt.cloudfront.net/assets/deleted/txt-discount-4666207b3ce9b9403bd940fec6d73139.gif) no-repeat;

}
```

I have no idea where its grabbing the `rtrtrtrtrtt.cloudfront.net` from. There is no mention of it anywhere in my source code or even if i do a grep in my VM. I explicitly state that my asset_host is `fffefeefefef.cloudfront.net`. `rtrtrtrtrtt.cloudfront.net` does exist in my aws account, but i do not want to use it for this project.

I have tried clearing my cache, restarting my VM, deleting everything from both buckets that both CDNs are attached to and running assets precompile, and deleting everything from public/assets. I have no idea where its getting the other CDN from.

Please help.

gems: rails 4.0.0, sprockets 2.10.1